# Why does e.g. Object inheritsFrom: fooobaar return true in Smalltalk?

Tags: inheritance, gnu, smalltalk

It seems that the inheritsFrom: method in GNU Smalltalk returns true for every undefined class name sent to it as a parameter. This might make a program very hard to debug, IMHO. Looking at the code for this in the Behavior class, it looks like this:

```
inheritsFrom: aClass [
"Returns true if aClass is a superclass of the receiver"

<category: 'testing the class hierarchy'>
| sc |
aClass isNil ifTrue: [^true].

sc := self.
[sc := sc superclass.
sc isNil] whileFalse: [sc == aClass ifTrue: [^true]].
^false
]
```

The line aClass isNil ifTrue: [^true] is the culprit, but I am looking for a sane reason as to way it was coded this way. (I am new to the Smalltalk world, by the way, and trying to learn.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not related to exceptions but rather to undefined variables.  In GNU Smalltalk's REPL, or alternatively in a Transcript or Workspace for graphical environments, undefined variables are all nil---this is not very different in Ruby, for example.

So you are doing in fact "Object inheritsFrom: nil", which is true.  I didn't know it is false in Squeak; that would be a departure from the Blue Book, actually.

In a method, you would have gotten a "variable fooobaar undefined" compile-time error.

Comment: Hum, Neil's answer (which I cannot comment directly) is wrong in that Object is not the superclass of everything.  In some sense, nil is the superclass of everything -- the Autoload class of GNU Smalltalk for example inherits directly from nil, not from Object, and there are many other examples.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the thinking is that all class references must imply a class of some sort so the nil reference implies Object, which is the superclass of everything.

[Squeak](http://www.squeak.org/) does it more the way you'd expect:

```
inheritsFrom: aClass 

|aSuperclass |
aSuperclass := superclass.
[aSuperclass == nil]
    whileFalse: [aSuperclass == aClass
            ifTrue: [^ true].
        aSuperclass := aSuperclass superclass].
^ false
```

[link text](http://www.squeak.org/)

Comment: While you are right that this is closer to my expectation, what I really would expect though was that there would be an exception thrown.

Comment: Smalltalk traditionally doesn't use exceptions very much.